# how select where and like in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a db with columns,in questo modo:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
static String DATABASE_NAME="calendarioDB";
public static final String CALENDARIO_TABLE="calendario";
public static final String CALENDARIO_ID="idcalendario";
public static final String ANNO="anno";
public static final String MESE="mese";
public static final String DATA="data";
```

If I run the select query so

```
Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.CALENDARIO_TABLE+" WHERE MESE LIKE 'Gen%'and ANNO = "+anno+"", null);
```

if I want to instead have only the date should I put

```
Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT DATA FROM " + DbHelper.CALENDARIO_TABLE+" WHERE MESE LIKE 'Gen%'and ANNO = "+anno+"", null);
```

but the app crashes.

Comment: What error message dod you get ? Please provide the stacktrace.

Comment: 04-03 13:43:27.478: E/AndroidRuntime(11316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 13:43:27.478: E/AndroidRuntime(11316): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to resume activity {calendario.db.tab/com.calendarioDB.calendarioDB}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {calendario.db.tab/mesi.Gennaio}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  
Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: if the select * with the query works, the database should be initialized correctly do not understand why it does not work with select by DATE

Comment: What is "questo modo"? And please change title to understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column is actually named `data`, not `DATA`. "DATA" is the variable name you're using.

So either do:

`"SELECT data FROM ...`

or

`"SELECT" + DbHelper.DATA + " FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

You're trying to access data in your cursor from a column that does not exist in the cursor. `getColumnIndex()` returns -1 if the column is not there.